# Imagem de background da activity distorce quando abre o teclado

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em que tem uma imagem de plano de fundo da imagem. Mas toda vez que eu abro o teclado virtual para preencher um campo, essa imagem fica achatada. Como faço para que isso não aconteça?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei um tópico muito semelhante no [stack overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287473/software-keyboard-resizes-background-image-on-android). Segundo ele, basta adicionar isso para a `Activity` no seu manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Parece que o problema é causado por haver uma `ScrollView` dentro da `Activity`.

Comment: É perfeitamente válido [traduzir](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/4337) uma pergunta do *SOen*, assim sua resposta não fica somente com um link, que algum dia pode não existir ou ficar indisponível.

Comment: É que eu não tinha certeza que iria responder a pergunta dele, mas anotado, será feito da próxima vez...